# Countable non-commutative groups such that all proper subgroups are commutative

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

Is there an infinite non-commutative group $G$ such that every proper subgroup of $G$ is commutative?

Comment: If $G$ is non-abelian and $x,y\in G$ with $xy\neq yx$ then the subgroup generated by $x$ and $y$ is countable and non-abelian.

Comment: Thanks - I'll reformulate my question, or remove it altogether

Comment: Yes, Tarski monsters. These are nonabelian groups in which every proper subgroup is cyclic (finite or infinite). They were constructed by Olshanskii (Gromov says they are easy to construct in his hyperbolic book, but that it's much much harder when the constraint is to have cyclic subgroups of bounded order).

Comment: Note that groups as in the question have the property that it's generated by any non-commuting pair.

Comment: It's pretty funny that a good third (maybe I'm exaggerating a bit) of group theory questions on MO have "Tarski monster" as answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @YCor. Maybe you can post this answer so we can close the question? Many thanks

Comment: @DenisT I don't know what you call a good approximation of "a good third" but there are about 5000 question tagged gr.group-theory and you'd have difficulty to find even 25 questions (half a percent) whose answer is given by Tarski monsters (and for which Tarski monsters are not part of the question).